# Why am I Getting 401 Unauthorized response from unsplash.com when I do an API request with react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've tried to do an API request to unsplash from react.js, it works when I pass the access key using a `client_id` query parameter like so:

```
axios.get("https://api.unsplash.com//search/photos/?client_id=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY"
```

but it doesn't work when I do it via the HTTP Authorization header like so:

```
onSearchSubmit(term) {
    axios.get("https://api.unsplash.com//search/photos", {
      params: { query: term },
      header: {
        Authorization: "Client-ID Yme6ZcumIXpWryQ0DPc249CE0ua2Mxh66Y-4W2gPAAc",
      },
      
    });
  }
```

it shows me this error:

> "OAuth error: The access token is invalid"

Comment: maybe because you are using `//` after `unsplash.com`

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot the 's' in the end, try to use this:

> headers: {
> Authorization: "Client-ID Yme6ZcumIXpWryQ0DPc249CE0ua2Mxh66Y-4W2gPAAc",   },

there are more ways to do a get request with axios, check it out the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)